# slicing photoshop template for iPhone

Tags: ios, photoshop

I am fairly new to building iPhone applications. I have a psd file with a template which I would like to use. How do people normally take the template and get images from it easily? Is there an easier way to do so? Another tool or some function in Photoshop?

Please let me know if there is another discussion on this, as I could not find any such information.

Comment: You can unlock all the layer and create png out off PSD and then you can use it in your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're a few tutorials on this online. But you can do all of it in Photoshop:

http://www.mygeekpal.com/how-to-slice-a-psd-file/